# waiting until page loads completely in selenium for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i make my code wait until the page load completely in Nodejs?
I use selenium-webdriver version 4.0.0

```
  const driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
  await driver.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F");
  // here we should wait but how?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 concepts here - there is:

- Page Load time - time for the page and content to download (...this downloads the scripts), then....
- Script load time - time for scripts to run, get more data and populate the page

[Page load time](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) is relatively easy - but this is enabled by default and might not help much if you're already experiencing issues.

For script load time, you need an object to synchronise on.
[The selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20setting%20an%20implicit,they%20are%20not%20immediately%20available.) give a good outline of different wait strategies and provide code examples for different languages.

Looking at your page, you will mostly likely want to try the explicit wait. In Javascript this is:

```
 await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('foo')), 30000);
```

You can update the `By` identifier to be the LAST item on the page or, use this approach for each item you need to interact with.

The same pages also lists other expected conditions too depending on the state you need.

A quick final note, if you're not aware [selenium 4 is still in alpha](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md). You can access it if you need the new features but they're still being testing and it is subject to frequent change. If you don't need selenium 4's new features, you might want to roll back to [latest stable version](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).